# Floating a FlexSlider Gallery

Tags: css-float, flexslider

I'm using the FlexSlider gallery script by WooThemes, and I would like the gallery to be 50% of the width of the parent container, and floated to the right. I added a "align_right" class to the FlexSlider div like this:

```
<div class="flexslider align_right">
    <ul class="slides">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

where the align_right class is defined as:

```
.align_right {
    max-width: 50%;
    float:right;
}
```

...and the entire gallery disappeared (except for a hint of the border). I even tried it on a fresh copy of the FlexSlider demo, and it still happens.

This method works fine for plain images and other gallery plugins; what do I need to do differently to get it to work with the FlexSlider gallery?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be ideal in all situations, but you can set the float after the slideshow has loaded:

```
  $(".flexslider").flexslider({
    start: function(){
      $(".flexslider").css({"float" : "right"});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. And thanks for answering 7 months later.